# Displaying other user's email address in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Trying to display a view that shows all registered users of the app along with their email addresses. I'm using this pub/sub to pass all user data to the client instead of just the current users data.

```
Meteor.publish("allUsers", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find();
  });

 Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
```

Here is the for each loop in my template that is supposed to display their emails:

```
<template name="daysOverview">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row"> 
{{#each users}}
<h2>Email: {{users.emails.[0].address}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

Here is the javascript that is supposed to loop over all of the current registered users and feed their data to the helper.

```
Template.daysOverview.helpers({
users: function(){
var user = Meteor.users.find(); 
return user; 
},
});
```

The helper correctly loops over the number of current users of the application (eg. if there are 3 users currently registered it will display 3 instances of "Email: " on the template).

The problem is that I can't find a way to access the email address of each user and display that next to the corresponding "Email: ". I tested accessing a simpler field like "_id" unsuccessfully as well.

I've also tried numerous different combinations of {{users.address}}, {{users[0].address}} to access the email with no luck.

Comment: Update: Figured out the answer; im a noob. 

    <template name="daysOverview">
    <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row"> 
 {{#each users}}
 <h2>Email: {{emails.[0].address}}</h2>
 {{/each}}

Don't call the {{users}} once you're inside your #each statement.

Comment: Make sure to use `fields` option when you publish users so you don't send things like the `services` field which contains things like the login tokens and the encrypted password.

Comment: @AlexNetsch, why not officially answer your own question since you figured it out?

Comment: Made me wait a few days before "answering my own question" and I forgot @IsaacGregson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{{#each users}}
    <h2>Email: {{emails.[0].address}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

Don't call `users` once you're inside your `{{#each users}}` block .